# Distributing N elements into K boxes with maximal capacity M

Tags: combinatorics

The question is the following: 
If we are taking 14 people on a trip, and 4 of them are driving, how can we distribute the remaining 10 if each car has 3 free seats?

My idea was to consider two possible distributions among cars: 3|3|3|1 and 3|3|2|2. Then I just need to choose which cars will get 3 people and I get that as ${4\choose 3}$ and ${4\choose 2}$. But now I don't know how to see in which combinations which people go to each of the cars (as I assume people are labled). However this doesn't seem like a sensible train of thought so any suggestions or hints are appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the sense that all of those are the possible arrangements. For the first arrangement: Do something like $\binom{10}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{3}\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot \binom{1}{1}$ so you are picking the people out of the $10$ remaining friends sequentially to form the arrangement $3|3|3|1.$ 
Notice that you need to multiply this by the $\binom{4}{3}$ that you computed to select the car in which there will be just the driver and one other friend. Do the same for the other arrangement and add them up.